# C - Check if last character of a string equals "#"

Tags: c

I want to check if the last character of my string is equal to a "#", and delete it if it is. However, I am unable to do a comparison. What is wrong with my code?

```
char* involved_node_string(int shared_val, int values[], int directions[]){;
    char involved_nodes[1024] = {};
    char *p = involved_nodes; 
    char result[1024];
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        if (values[k] == shared_val){
            sprintf(result, "%d", directions[k]);
            strcat(involved_nodes, result);
            strcat(involved_nodes, "#");                                
        }
    }
    char v = p[strlen(p)-1];
    if (v == "#"){
        printf("Yes\n");    
    }


    return p;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message from the compiler? If so, what exactly is the message, and which part of it don't you understand? You have to provide more details, otherwise we cannot help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of [How does c compare character variable against string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31406415/11683), which it is. The OP accepted the duplicate. Then a golden badge user reopened it. I do wonder why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the issue be that you are comparing a `char` (`v`) to a string-literal (`"#"`)? Maybe try using the expression `(v == '#')` (using single quotes instead of double quotes to denote a `char`) and see if that works?